# Duplicate question deleted by Community

Tags: bug

It was recently brought to our attention that [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/8706/102) has been automatically deleted by the Community user, which also deleted some comment on this question. To the best of my knowledge, the Community user is not controlled by the moderators of this site, and I would guess it's either automated or controlled by a global moderator. I was aware that Community could delete comments of destroyed users, or automatically flag some content, but I didn't know that it could delete such content.

Since the normal rule is to say that we do not delete duplicate questions, I'm not sure why this question has been deleted, could a global moderator (or someone who knows what happened) provide some explanation?

Answer (score 3):

We just had a long discussion about this in [mod chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9108141#9108141) (mod-only, sorry), which led to me posting [this request on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177627/reconsider-community-deletions-on-closed-downvoted-questions-when-closed-becaus).

Long story short, it was closed because [Community deletes closed, downvoted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175249/why-was-this-native-not-migrated-question-deleted-by-community).

Comment: Thanks, I found the mod-chat so hard to read through that I practically never go there.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset  Heh, you mean you find seven simultaneous conversations to be confusing? No way! :)

Comment: yeah ... it's a shame, if only there was system where mods could ask questions to each other and answer them, and where the mods could up vote/downvote them ... if only such a system would exist ... :)

Comment: The question has now been undeleted. I just gave it an up vote so it shouldn't get auto deleted again. I guess as individuals we need to think about up/down voting duplicates.